# Rails test not working with model methods in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

When testing with rails, calling model methods within a view doesn't work. Is there a reason for this? The functions all work when accessing the page within the browser with no issue.

The view line causing problems:

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@project.assignment_options(current_user)),
            { include_blank: "Teammate to assign" }, class: "uk-select uk-margin-small-right" %>
```

The Test:

```
  def current_user
    @user
  end
  
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user
    @project = projects(:one)
    @project.owner_id = @user.id
    @assignment = assignments(:one)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get new_project_assignment_url(@project.slug)
    assert_response :success
  end
```

The Error:

```
E

Error:
AssignmentsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: Couldn't find User without an ID
    app/models/project.rb:33:in `owner'
    app/models/project.rb:63:in `assignment_options'
    app/views/assignments/_form.html.erb:6
    app/views/assignments/_form.html.erb:2
    app/views/assignments/new.html.erb:2
    test/controllers/assignments_controller_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:AssignmentsControllerTest>'
```

When I do a "puts current_user.id" from within the view and test they match, so there is definitely a user id available on the page, but I am still hitting this issue. I have tried making tests for different pages that have different model methods, and they all fail with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I wasn't saving the updated project. I needed to use @project.update. There was a strange behavior that when I updated the owner_id, the slug also updated for no apparent reason, but I worked around it by just creating a new project instead of using a fixture.